# calling a custom get method in web api

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a custom method named getbyemail in web api

```
[HttpGet]
   [Route("api/drive/{getbyemail}/{email}")]
   //[ActionName("GetByString")]
   [WebMethod]
   [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
   public IEnumerable<object> GetByEmail(string email)
   {
       using (var db1 = new TestContext())
       {
           var results = from d in db1.table1
                         where d.email == email
                         select d;

           return results;
       }
  }'
```

I have added a route for this method in WebApiConfig file as:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultStringApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{email}",
        //defaults: new { Action = "GetByString", email = RouteParameter.Optional }
        defaults: new { email = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "API Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

And i am calling this method using jquery call as:

```
 <script >
  function findByEmail() {
      alert('enter');
      var email = $('#useremail').val();
      var Url = "api/drive/getbyemail";
      $.ajax({
          type: "Get",
          dataType: "json",
          url: Url + '/' + email,
          success: function (data) {
          alert('success');
          //formatItem(item);
      },
      error: function (x, y, z) {

          var strResult = "<table><th>Error Message</th>";

          strResult += "<tr><td> " + x.responseText + " </td></tr>"
          strResult += "</table>";
          $("#divResult").html(strResult);
      }

  });
  }
```

but it gives the error as:

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm wormly recommend you carefully reading the article [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) which explains the technique in details with excellent examples.

Specifically in your case, it seems (I cannot be sure while seeing only a small part of your code, but I'am almost sure) that you should remove brackets from  `getbyemail`, so it should be:

```
 [Route("api/drive/getbyemail/{email}")]
```

where `drive` is the controller name (`DriveController`, isn't it?), `getbyemail` is a method name and `email` is a parameter.

Name in brackets is a variable, so your could route to this method something like "`api/drive/getbyid/33`", while in fact you mean only an exact path like "`api/drive/getbyemail/mail@server.ext`"

UPDATE:

Normalize your script code:

```
function findByEmail() {
      var email = $('#useremail').val();
      var Url = "api/drive/getbyemail";
      var data = { email: email };
      $.ajax({
          type: "Get",
          url: Url,
          data: data,
          dataType: "text"
      }).success: function (data) {
          alert('success');
      }).error: function (data) {
          alert('error');
      });
```

Read more about [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: I removed the brackets ,but it still gives the same error HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
 while the requested url is correct as it comes out to be  http://localhost:2830/api/drive/GetByEmail/smriti@gmail.com

Comment: You provided only a small part of code, so it's not possible to investigate the problem. What is your controller name? What is the directory structure? Do you have other methods in the same controller and what are their route attributes? Try to localize the problem by removing the side effects from other code parts.

Comment: It works for  localhost:2830/api/drive/GetByEmail/smriti                                      But not for  localhost:2830/api/drive/GetByEmail/smriti@gmail.com                  Why?

Comment: My controller is DriveController. The other methods in this controller have default route as:

Comment: config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "API Default",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

Comment: I just changed routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{email}/", means added a "/" after {email} in webapiconfig and in the controller and it started working